# C# WPF static resource containing other static resources

Tags: c#, string, wpf, xaml, staticresource

I've just started learning WPF but I can't seem to figure out how to combine two or more string static resources in XAML. I have two static resources, `UntitledFileName` ("Untitled") and `ApplicationName` ("SomeAppName"). The third resource, `DefaultWindowTitle`, should be composed of the aforementioned resources, and should contain the value "Untitled - SomeAppName". How should I specify the two static resources when defining `DefaultWindowTitle`?

```
<sys:String x:Key="UntitledFileName">Untitled</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="ApplicationName">SomeAppName</sys:String>
<sys:String x:Key="DefaultWindowTitle">...</sys:String>
```

Comment: No way. XAML is a declarative language, not an algorithmic one.
You can convert both strings to one by setting the DependencyProperty to MultiBining using StringFormat.

Comment: I would suggest two runs in a textblock. Text of each run set to a staticresource and hence appear concatenated in one textblock. A textblock is the closest equivalent to a label in other tech.

Comment: I was planning to use "DefaultWindowTitle" as the window's title.

Answer (score 0):

> I was planning to use "DefaultWindowTitle" as the window's title.

Perhaps this implementation will suit you:

```xml
<Window.Title>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource UntitledFileName}"/>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource ApplicationName}"/>
    <MultiBinding>
</Window.Title>
```